# How to Reload a Script with Infinite Scroll?

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm making use of the following script to equal the height of floated div's on my website:

```
equalheight = function (container) {

var currentTallest = 0,
    currentRowStart = 0,
    rowDivs = new Array(),
    $el,
    topPosition = 0;
$(container).each(function () {

    $el = $(this);
    $($el).height('auto')
    topPostion = $el.position().top;

    if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
        for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
            rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
        }
        rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
        currentRowStart = topPostion;
        currentTallest = $el.height();
        rowDivs.push($el);
    } else {
        rowDivs.push($el);
        currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
    }
    for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
        rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
    }
});
}

$(window).load(function () {
equalheight('.gallery-item');
});


$(window).resize(function () {
equalheight('.gallery-item');
});
```

I'm also making use of the Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll plugin:

```
    $(function () {
    $('.container').infinitescroll({
        navSelector: '.navigation',
        nextSelector: '.navigation ul li.older a',
        itemSelector: '.event',
        bufferPx: 600,
        animate: true,
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: 'No more articles to load!',
            img: 'images/loader.gif',
            speed: 0
        }
    }, function (newElements) {
        Cufon.refresh();
    });
});
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to reload the equalheight script with the NewElements function when Infinite Scroll has fetched new items. Is that possible, and if so, what should I write up there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure, but try adding `equalheight('.gallery-item');` in your anonymous function after `Cufon.refresh();`

Comment: Thanks, Rajesh! It seems that your solution affects the equalheight script but not in a proper way. DIV's are getting the same height but are placed half on top of each other.